# AttributeError: 'datetime.date' object has no attribute 'date'

Tags: python

I have a script like this:

```
import datetime

# variable cal_start_of_week_date has type <type 'datetime.date'>
# variable period has type <type 'datetime.timedelta'>

cal_prev_monday  = (cal_start_of_week_date - period).date()
```

When the above statement is executed, I get the error:

AttributeError: 'datetime.date' object has no attribute 'date'

How to fix this?

Comment: just remove `.date()` from the end?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Stop trying to call the `date()` method of a `date` object. It's already a `date`.

Comment: Hmmm, you're right. I wonder if could have been possible to name the objects and attributes in the datetime module in a way that could possibly be more confusing to beginners...

Answer (score 9):

.date() method exists only on datetime.datetime objects. You have object of datetime.date type.

Remove method call and be happy.