# 'datetime.time' object has no attribute 'date' in django admin

Tags: python, django, flutter

I'm trying to open an object in my Django application /admin, but this object gives me the error 
`'datetime.time' object has no attribute 'date` despite I have no special calls or variables inside the model, here is the model :

**IMPORTANT**: it works normally as expected when running dev server on `127.0.0.1:8000` but it only fails on my online VPS with apache server.

**I HAVE UPDATED CODES TO BE**

removing the time field and only uses the date_time field now.

```py
class LeaveRequest(models.Model):
    options = (
        ('Leave', 'Leave'),
        ('Absence', 'Absence'),
    )
    choices = (
        ('Approved', 'Approved'),
        ('Rejected', 'Rejected'),
        ('Pending', 'Pending'),
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="leaverequest_user", on_delete=CASCADE)
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, related_name="leaverequest_employee", on_delete=CASCADE)
    type = models.CharField(choices=options, max_length=50)
    status = models.CharField(choices=choices, max_length=50)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    date_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=False, null=True)
```

**note** am adding data field and DateTime field because I have 2 different types of requests that one only depends on the date and the other depends on date and time.

**UPDATE**

Am using `Django rest framework` API calls to create this object, here is the code :

**api.serializers.py**

```py
class RequestSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = LeaveRequest
        fields = ["user", "employee", "type", "status", "text", "date_time"]
```

**api.views.py**

```py
@api_view(["POST", ])
def create_leave_request(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.data['username']
        user_obj = User.objects.get(username=username)
        employee_id = request.data['employee_id']
        employee_obj = Employee.objects.get(id=employee_id)
        the_type = request.data['type']
        state = "Pending"
        text = request.data['text']
        date_time_qs = request.data['date_time']
        date_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_time_qs, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
        LeaveRequest.objects.create(user=user_obj, employee=employee_obj, type=the_type, status=state, text=text,
                                    date_time=date_time)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

And here is the API call that comes from my `flutter` android app :

```dart
  sendingRequest() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String username = prefs.getString('user');
    int employee_id = prefs.getInt('id');
    String url = 'https://www.g-attend.com/api/panel/request/create';
    var client = Client();
    await client.post(url, headers: {
      "Authorization": "Basic Z19hdHRlbmRfYWRtaW5AZy1hdHRlbmQuY29tOllhaG9vMDAwQA==",
    }, body: {
      "username": username,
      "employee_id": employee_id.toString(),
      "type": "Leave",
      "text": reasonController.text,
      "date_time": "${_dateTime.year}-${_dateTime.month.toString().padLeft(
          2, '0')}-${_dateTime.day.toString().padLeft(2, '0')} ${_dateTime.hour
          .toString().padLeft(2, '0')}:${_dateTime.minute.toString().padLeft(
          2, '0')}"
    });
    client.close();
    Toast.show(
        "Succesfuly sent Leave request on ${_dateTime.year}-${_dateTime.month
            .toString().padLeft(2, '0')}-${_dateTime.day.toString().padLeft(
            2, '0')} ${_dateTime.hour.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}:${_dateTime
            .minute.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}", context,
        duration: Toast.LENGTH_LONG, gravity: Toast.CENTER);
    Navigator.pop(context);
  }
```

**UPDATE**

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3195405/attributeerror-datetime-date-object-has-no-attribute-date) wasn't helpful in my case as he was getting this error when he called `.date()` at the query, but I am not calling anything as I get this error inside the Django admin which is already built-in.

Comment: can you paste the object creation/save code?

Comment: @HoratiuJeflea done, check update, please

Comment: can you set in the views.py, the `time` to `datetime.datetime.now()` and the `date` to `datetime.datetime.now().date()`? Want to check something

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: 'datetime.date' object has no attribute 'date'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3195405/attributeerror-datetime-date-object-has-no-attribute-date)

Comment: @HoratiuJeflea  did it, nothing changed, still, the `datetime` field which is called `time` is not saving.

Comment: @Ovidiu no, in this question the user was calling .date(), am not calling anything as it is in the Django admin page, which is built-in already.

Comment: can't find the issue... sorry

Comment: `time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=False, null=True)` This one might be the issue - shouldn't that be a `models.TimeField` instead of a `models.DateTimeField`?

Comment: Please post the full traceback.

Comment: @AhmedWagdi You are very clearly calling `datetime.datetime.strptime(date_qs, "%Y-%m-%d").date()`, which is failing for a reason that's very clearly explained in the other article that I linked above.

Comment: @AhmedWagdi have you checked if your migrations are up to date?

Comment: @Ovidiu I've already removed .date() since the beginning but just forgot to update the code, please check-update

Comment: it strange that it works locally on 127.0.0.1:8000 but not when I run on my prod server that uses apache on ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dropping the current PostgreSQL database and creating new one solved it !!!